# Why are we getting low download speed as compared to the our bandwidth from browser?

Tags: networking, download, lan, bandwidth

Our bandwidth is 16Mbps 1:1 leased line, and we have been getting download speed of about 1.3+ MB/S earlier.
But for 2 weeks we are getting a maximum of just 150-200 KB/S although the speed test result shows 16Mbps.

I have tried connecting directly by setting static IP, but still the same results.
However, I'm getting max-speed when downloading a torrent file or from Google playstore but browsing or downloading from any browser is very slow.
Also while updating or installing packages via `yum` package manager or `apt-get`, the speed is even worse.

Comment: Have you tested at different types of day (non-peak times)? and with different machines?

Comment: Yes, I did. We are connected to PF-Sense firewall and the monthly usage graphs from it shows an average of just 6 MB/S

Comment: So the box in question is a rack you are remoted into, and you're downloading to the rack? Is it a virtual machine or dedicated? What linux distro are you using? Is cpu usage perhaps the bottleneck? (Unlikely but plausible if you're in a shared space, check `top`). Any other users remoted into the machine and using bandwidth?

Comment: Hi, linux distro or cpu usage is not the problem. I have connected the whole dedicated isp line to my lap, still I'm getting the same results.  i.e slow speed from browser & terminal. This issue started just 2 weeks ago
But max speed when downloading something from torrents or google playstore.

Comment: I suggest we move this to serverfault; a better audience for non-home-networking issues. (Have you filed a ticket with your rack host?)

Comment: Hi, It was the servers, I was connecting to! Downloading from different sites had different speeds. I realized When I tried downloading from Norton and Microsoft software's., It was in max speed..Still don't know why. "YUM " package manager is Damn slow (<100 KBp/s). Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several factors in download speed.  It could be the servers you are connecting to.  You might try downloading from a different location to compare.

Traffic shaping has been mentioned. This can happen on the local network, at the ISP or in the public network.  And this can take the form of hard limits or be based on current load, traffic patterns or phases of the moon.

Where are you running the speed test?  Is it an ISP site or a public site like speedtest.net?  It needs to be a public site.  Having a fast connection to your ISP does not guarantee a fast connection to the Internet (which is supposed to be the point).

There could be other issues, but if you are not noticing lots of drops and consistently getting good speed tests, then I would focus on what's already mentioned.

Comment: Hi, I have run tests from speedtest.net. It shows download and upload speed of nearly 16Mbs.
We are connected to PF-Sense firewall and the monthly usage graphs shows an average of just 6 MB/S.
The graph goes peak upto 12Mbs when downloading a torrent file or from playstore. I dont know why browsers gives just 200kb/s

Comment: Have you tried bypassing the firewall?  You basically need to narrow down where the issue is.  It might be the firewall.  If not, rule it out by testing.  I see that PF-Sense is an open-source firewall.  There may be a default configuration or bad configuration working against you.  It would most likely be traffic shaping/quota.  I've messed this up before and had the same issues. This makes sense as it is usually not the ISP causing the issue.

Comment: pfsense allows for port-based traffic shaping. perhaps port 80 http is throttled

Comment: Hi, All the ports are open completely in firewall. Forget about pf-sense. As stated in description, I have directly connected the isp line to my lap. Still I am getting same results.. i.e slow speed from browser & terminal.
This issue started just 2 weeks ago. But max speed when downloading something from torrents or google playstore.

Comment: i'm only mentioning pf-sense because it is in-line with your connection to the Internet.  If you call the ISP they are going to want you to test with a direct connection.  Your issue seems to be with http(s) traffic (not speed test).  I think this is just restating your issue.  The only other thing I can think of is antivirus/antimalware software.  If you are convinced that this is not hte issue, then calling the ISP is probably the best next step.  JMHO

Comment: Hi, It was the servers, I was connecting to! Downloading from different sites had different speeds. When I tried downloading Norton antivirus, it was in max speed..Still don't know why. "YUM " package manager is Damn slow (<100 KBp/s). Any solution for this ?

Comment: YUM pulls from repos.  What repo do you have set up?  You may just need to configure a different repo server.

Answer (score 0):

ISPs frequently apply [traffic shaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping) to throttle certain types of traffic at peak times. This is especially true of torrents.

Requiring encrypted-transport can offset this somewhat.

If the situation does not improve reboot router and complain to ISP.

Answer (score -3):

Depending on the kind of torrents you are downloading, then using a VPN service might be a wonderful idea.

https://torrentfreak.com/which-vpn-providers-really-take-anonymity-seriously-111007/

ALso, change your DNS to an uncensored one.

http://blog.uncensoreddns.org/en
www.censurfridns.dk

Comment: How does changing your dns improve download speed?

Comment: The ISP should be bypassed in every way possible if we feel that they are responsible for "shaping" our traffic.

Also, I might add that some torrent clients are just faster (better at managing bandwidth) than others. Vuze, for example, will kill the Internet in your place, but it will fly downloading P2P.